# Убрать пробелы и подобрать регулярное выражение

Tags: регулярные-выражения, php

Уважаемое, сообщество! Прошу помочь сформировать регулярное выражение, но проблема еще не только в этом.

Поясню суть всего происходящего более подробно.

**Получаю с другого сайта цену товара:**

[image]

*код получения цены:*

```
//  Получение содержимого страницы
    $html = file_get_contents($url);

//  Обработка данных HTML-DOM
    $doc = \phpQuery::newDocumentHTML($html);

//  Получение в DOM цену
    $price = trim($doc['.big-price']->html());

    echo "цена - $price"; // здесь будет 5&nbsp;599,00 руб

//  удаляем пробелы
    $price = preg_replace("/(&nbsp;)|(\s)|( )/", '', $price);

    echo "цена: $price"; // а здесь будет 5&nbsp;599,00руб
```

**Запускаю сценарий через консоль и смотрю вывод:**

[image]

**Вижу, что функция выпилила только один пробел после дробной части цены, хотя в шаблоне регулярки я указал все необходимые вхождения.**

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что я делаю не так?

Comment: 1. Используйте модификатор "u", чтобы работать с юникод-строками
2. Посмотрите на ASCII-код этих пробелов, вполне может быть, что это не 0x20, а что-то в духе 0х00A0, 0х202F и тому подобное.

Comment: @Johny посмотрел с помощью функции chr(), которая вернула мне значение этого пробела 160 в таблице ASCII. Это символ и есть &nbsp;

Comment: Ну так вы тогда именно его в регулярке и используйте! ))

Т.е. не последовательность символов "&nbsp;", а сам пробел - символ с кодом 160

Кстати, часть "(\s)|( )" можно заменить на "[\s ]" ;-)

Comment: Т.е. регулярка может иметь такой вид

    "/(&nbsp;)|[\s\x00A0]/u"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Попробуйте конвертировать из html-entities в utf-8.
У меня это работает.

```
$price = "цена - 5&nbsp;599,00 руб"; // здесь будет 5&nbsp;599,00 руб
$price = mb_convert_encoding($price, 'HTML-ENTITIES', 'UTF-8');

$price = preg_replace("/(&nbsp;)|(\s)|( )/", '', $price);
```

Comment: Не удивляйтесь, если потом вылезут всякие *&ndash;*, *&rsquo;*, *&prime;* и прочие радости...

Answer (score 0):

Попробуй перед `$price = preg_replace("/(&nbsp;)|(\s)|( )/", '', $price);` сделать `$price=strip_tags($price);`.

Comment: @Diefair, не сработало, к сожалению. (

Comment: `$price=preg_replace("/[^0-9,]+/i", "", $price);`

Comment: @Diefair, попробовал, не сработало.